# Zoom in TeXShop Macbook

Tags: zooming

In TeXShop LaTeX PDF preview window, sometimes when I double or triple click on the preview window I get this rectangle magnifier. I've seen in my friends Windows computer that this is a standard thing, but on TeXShop this seems to be some bug of some kind. My question is how can one get this rectangle magnifier in Macbook TeXShop TeXLive?

**EDIT**: Ha ok, but I think I actually just "found" out how to activate this, it almost works 100% of the time: I double press down on the Macbook trackpad. If I triple press then the larger rectangle magnifier appears and so on until all of the screen is magnified. Interesting.

Comment: I've never seen the magnifier in TeXShop's previewer by clicking; there's the icon in the top bar for it. You're probably confusing it with TeXworks, that also run under Windows.

Comment: Yes that's strange but I promise you if you click randomly and moving the cursor the rectangle magnifier shows up. That why I found this interesting.

Comment: I should add that I click on a white space where no text appears (otherwise one would just select the text and no magnifier would appear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally click on one of the magnifier glass icons in the top bar

[image]

If you then click-drag over the text you get magnified view in a rectangle; pressing the Alt key turns the whole window into magnified view.

Double clicking and then keeping the button pressed is equivalent to selecting the small magnifier glass. Triple clicking and then keeping the button pressed is equivalent to selecting the large magnifier glass.

Comment: Ha ok, I had never seen those icons because my window is always set to a non-wide size. Yes I found out, see edit of question.